# cannot get (external) links within phonegap remote web app to open externally in saffari

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have created a phonegap app that redirects to the actual app on a remote server simply using window.location when deviceReady. The reason for this is that although the app is very native looking and functional, the content has to be updated daily and as it seems using json or rss feeds is quite complicated this seemed like the obvious choice. Everything works great apart from links i have to external websites, these open within the app and then i cannot get back to my app. I would like them to open externally to the app in say ios safari. I have thoroughly searched the internet and tried all sorts of things such as whitelisting and using window.open and cordovas inappbrowser option, however it seems the config.xml no longer applies once you are already in an external window (or maybe im doing something wrong?). Is there any way to fix this issue without having to start over and try and use json/rss i am desperate!

Comment: Have you considered React Native instead? Seriously, it's much better than Phonegap.

Comment: Thats not quite the solution I was thinking of!

Comment: Haha I know, just saying... IDK what to do about your problem w/ Phonegap.